# Many Linux network drivers have been found to leak data in such situations

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I am reading LDD and have a question about below statement

"Do note, however, the care that is taken when the packet to be transmitted is shorter than the minimum length supported by the underlying media (which, for snull, is our virtual “Ethernet”). Many Linux network drivers have been found to leak data in such situations."

Could you please tell me why drivers may leak data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their point is that with an ethernet card, for example, the minimum packet size is 60 bytes (to which the card will typically add a frame checksum making minimum 64-bytes on the wire). If the payload you are sending is 60 bytes long or more, then, the card will send exactly the data you have given it.

If you hand it, say, only 40 bytes, then it will still transmit 60 bytes - the 40 bytes you gave it *plus the next 20 bytes* that happen to be sitting in the buffer beyond the 40 you intended to send.

If you haven't explicitly initialized that area, those 20 bytes might well be data leftover from a previously sent packet, which may have belonged to some other connection. Or that memory could have previously been a data page for some program that was recently running (and hence could contain a password, or an encryption key or just about any kind of sensitive information).

This is a data leak (not to be confused with a buffer leak). That LDD text is cautioning that you need to make sure to zero out those bytes in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  so it is not about the data leak for this intended packet.  it is actually for previous data. right ?

Comment: Correct. It's about leaking previous data that happens to still be sitting in a not-overwritten part of the buffer.